# Repacking Vagrant box : Updates not reflecting

Tags: vagrant, websphere, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

We are using vagrant: 2.0.3. and provider VirtualBox: 5.2.10.

Our client had delivered a .box file with base softwares like WebSphere, java etc.
I have to update WebSphere configuration to our application specific and create a new .box file with all  new configuration.I have created new box using
command

```
vagrant box repackage NAME PROVIDER VERSION
```

And I have configured newly created .box, However after running new box, the WebSphere does not have the changes I have updated.

Could you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to repackage the box after you make your changes.

1. `vagrant up` the VM with your customer box file
2. do all changes to config files, etc
3. `vagrant box repackage NAME PROVIDER VERSION` will package as a new box file the current state of the VM so it will contain all the changes.

Comment: Unfortunately its not working :( ...Still  newly created box don't have the changes I have updated...Specifically, I have modified Websphere application config in customer provided box and in new repacked box, i am see  only changes customer provide one..My changes are lost..

Comment: do you have provisioning script that could change those values ?

Answer (score 0):

Repacking worked when I explicilty passed --vagrantfile param in package command like below.

```
vagrant package --base ae611070-a886-4808-9904-3ff1a1ff46bb --output mynewvm.box --vagrantfile C:\Users\Prasobh\.vagrant.d\boxes\myoldvm\0\virtualbox\include\_Vagrantfile
```